# propagation of contents of argc and argv by MPI runtime

Tags: mpi, command-line-arguments

Is it valid for a conformant MPI program to rely on the MPI runtime to start the process for each rank with the same contents of argc and argv? Or is it necessary to e.g. broadcast things from a designated master rank?

Answer (score 4):

Just to be clear, it is only guaranteed that argc/argv are define *after* the call to MPI_Init(), even though the processes all exist before the call. This is why MPI_Init() takes *pointers* to argc and argv, specifically to enable them to be initialised on all processes by the MPI_Init() call.

It is therefore essential that you use:

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
```

and not

```
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
```

In practice, many MPI implementations make the command-line arguments available before the Init call, but you should not rely on this.

Comment: That advice is out of date as of MPI 2.0. See https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-2.0/node43.htm. Conforming implementations are required to allow NULL to be passed. (That's different from the requirement of the original question, about whether the command-line arguments are made available by the runtime in argc+argv before process launch.)

Answer (score 2):

The standard doesn't make it clear whether that is the case or not as it tries too hard to abstract the actual process by which the MPI ranks come into existence.

On one side, Section 8.8 *Portable MPI Process Startup* recommends that a portable process launcher by the name of `mpiexec` exists (if required at all by the execution environment) and it is advisable that the launcher be able to be viewed as command-line version of `MPI_COMM_SPAWN`.

On the other side, `MPI_COMM_SPAWN` takes among its arguments an array of command-line arguments to be passed on to the spawned processes and those are supposed to be passed on (Section 10.3.2 *Starting Processes and Establishing Communication*):

> Arguments are supplied to the program if this is allowed by the operating system. [...]

But the paragraph following the cited one is:

> If a Fortran implementation supplies routines that allow a program to obtain its arguments, the arguments **may** be available through that mechanism. In C, if the operating system does not support arguments appearing in `argv` of `main()`, the MPI implementation **may** add the arguments to the `argv` that is passed to MPI_INIT. *(emphasis mine)*

I would therefore read this as: MPI implementations are advised to make their best to provide all ranks with the command-line arguments of the `mpiexec` command, but no absolute guarantee is given.